# Is there a way to check my loadout from inside a game?

Tags: airmech

Pushing the numbers 1 through 8 builds units, but what if I didn't check what units were set to what place? Is there any way to check what unit is on each number, or do I just have to go through building them to see what it builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Q, or use the mouse wheel.